# Display folder for replace my domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi i have a url like **aaa.com/folder** but its possible to directly display just **aaa.com** ?

I have already test this in htaccess

```
   <VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerAdmin webmaster@siteprincipal.com 
DocumentRoot /public_html/porn
ServerName www.siteprincipal.com 
ServerAlias siteprincipal.com 
CustomLog logs/principal-access_log combined 
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/principal/cgi-bin/ 
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: DocumentRoot is the folder you get when you enter www.siteprincipal.com. Change DocumentRoot to the proper folder and restart the webserver.

Comment: I have just acce to htaccess not the server i have change this by my folder but i have error 500 internal

Answer (score 0):

> Hi i have a url like aaa.com/folder but its possible to directly display just aaa.com ?

First, get rid of what stuff in your htaccess. None of that stuff belongs in the htaccess file, they all belong in your server's vhost config.

You need to make sure mod_rewrite is turned on, then just add in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^(?!folder/) /folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```